# Most Pythonic for / enumerate loop?

Tags: python, enumerate

I have a loop condition:

```
for count, item in enumerate(contents):
```

but only want to use the first 10 elements of contents. What is the most pythonic way to do so?

Doing a:

```
if count == 10: break
```

seems somewhat un-Pythonic. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you using `enumerate()` for anything other than to detect that you have looped over the first 10 items?

Comment: Yep, I am using the 'item' term to do some parsing before adding them to another list.

Comment: @Dirk His question means that, are you using `count` any where else in the loop, apart from using it as a flag to `break`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a slice (slice notation)

```
for count, item in enumerate(contents[:10]):
```

If you are iterating over a generator, or the items in your list are large and you don't want the overhead of creating a new list (as slicing does) you can use [`islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) from the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools) module:

```
for count, item in enumerate(itertools.islice(contents, 10)):
```

---

Either way, I suggest you do this in a robust manner, which means wrapping the functionality inside a function (as one is want to do with such functionality - indeed, it is the reason for the name function)

```
import itertools

def enum_iter_slice(collection, slice):
    return enumerate(itertools.islice(collection, slice))
```

Example:

```
>>> enum_iter_slice(xrange(100), 10)
<enumerate object at 0x00000000025595A0>
>>> list(enum_iter_slice(xrange(100), 10))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9)]
>>> for idx, item in enum_iter_slice(xrange(100), 10):
    print idx, item

0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
```

---

If you were using enumerate and your `count` variable just to check the items index (so that using your method you could exit/break the loop on the 10th item.) You don't need enumerate, and just use the [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) all on its own as your function.

```
for item in itertools.islice(contents, 10):
```

Answer (score 6):

If the list is large or `contents` is a generator, use [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

for count, item in enumerate(islice(contents, 10)):
```

For smaller lists or tuples, just use slicing:

```
for count, item in enumerate(contents[:10]):
```

Slicing creates a new list or tuple object, which for 10 items is not that big a deal.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to the two answers already given:

I propose to *think* about the situation you are in.  *Why* is is that you want to do 10 iterations and no more?  Is it more the wish to abort after ten cycles (e. g. because each cycle takes up a long time and the whole runtime shall be limited while giving up completeness) or is the reason behind your requirement that the first ten elements are a special group of items (maybe the ten to display)?

In the first case I'd say the most correct way would actually be the `if ... break` you proposed because it represents your thoughts most direct.

In the latter case I'd propose to name the child, i. e. introduce a speaking name for that special group of the first ten elements (e. g. `elements_to_display`) and iterate over them.